# How to handle gpg-agent in WSL?

Tags: gnupg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gpg-agent

I was trying to release a Jar and the gpg-agent was not starting. According to https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html it should start automatically on any invocation of a GnuPG program but that doesn't seem to be true in WSL.

```
pupeno@DESKTOP-5N8VFOD:~$ gpg-agent
gpg-agent: no gpg-agent running in this session
```

For a moment I thought that maybe GnuPG would just not work in WSL, but I managed to started manually:

```
pupeno@DESKTOP-5N8VFOD:~$ eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
pupeno@DESKTOP-5N8VFOD:~$ gpg-agent
gpg-agent: gpg-agent running and available
```

So, what's missing? Why isn't it starting automatically? or how should I start it?

Comment: Did you try running `$ gpg`? I've come across a related problem when using a yubikey where I need to kill `gpg-agent`. In this case, I simply run `$ gpg --card-edit` and it starts back up.

Answer (score 4):

You want `gpg-agent` to start automatically, so start it from `~/.bashrc`.

```
echo 'eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: If you're using a console emulator like ConEmu with WSL, this will start a new gpg-agent for every tab.

Comment: I get `gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one` when starting new WSL windows and tabs.